# Cannot Insert Multiple Rows in Loop - Jtable

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm having strange issue, not sure if I'm doing something wrong. But here is my issue:

I'm working on developing custom helpdesk component. I have custom save method in my Model as follows:

```
public function save($data, $table)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $type = 'error';

        if (!$table->bind($data))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$table->check())
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
           $table->store();             
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $app->enqueueMessage($ex->getMessage(), $type);

            return false;
        }

        return $table;
    }
```

I also have custom function which returns uploaded file information like name, size, type etc. User can upload more than one file that's the reason, I put that information in an Array as follows:

```
foreach ($filesArr as $file)
{
    $uploads[] = array(
       'hid' => $response->id,
       'name' => $file['name'],
       'size' => $file['size']
     );
}
```

Output of $uploads[] looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [hid] => 2 [name] => request-for-proprietary-information.pdf [size] => 379984 )
[1] => Array ( [hid] => 2 [name] => vendor-contracting-and-oversight.pdf [size] => 416834 ) )
```

I went ahead and put it in foreach loop to get each array and then save it in my database.

```
foreach ($uploads as $upload)
{
     $table = $model->save($upload, $attachment); // Calling save function as mentioned above.
     if ($table === false)
     {
      $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('COM_HELPDESK_UPLOAD_ERROR'), 'error');
     }
}
```

Here is structure of my table:
[image: Structure of My table where data is supposed to save]

Please note that, my Primary key is "ID" which is set on AUTO_INCREMENT.
"hid" is not Primary Key.

Above code inserts 1st row in database and then for the rest of loop it just updates the 1st row only.

> Query Time: 1.00 ms After last query: 1.00 ms Query memory: 0.009 MB
>   Memory before query: 7.060 MB
>
> INSERT INTO `jos_helpdesk_attachment` (`hid`,`name`,`size`)    VALUES 
>   ('2','request-for-proprietary-information.pdf','379984')
>
> Query Time: 2.00 ms After last query: 1.00 msQuery memory: 0.009 MB
>   Memory before query: 7.068 MB
>
> UPDATE `jos_helpdesk_attachment`    SET
>   `hid`='2',`name`='vendor-contracting-and-oversight.pdf',`size`='416834'
>   WHERE `id`='1'

Comment: I don't think you need to put `if(!$table->store())` inside a `try` clause. Simply do `try { $table->store(); }`. This isn't the answer to your question, just an off-topic comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really strange!. I resolved this issue. But I had to explicitly pass "id" column to an array. Hence, I added "id" (primary) key to my existing code:

```
 foreach ($filesArr as $file)
    {
        $uploads[] = array(
           'id' => '',
           'hid' => $response->id,
           'name' => $file['name'],
           'size' => $file['size']
         );
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful for others.

Comment: The problem was that JTable updates its internal properties after the first save, which sets the ID to the first record created. So after the first save, it updates that record. What you're doing by sending the empty I'd value is unsetting the internal ID manually. You could also call JTable::reset at the beginning of each loop and it would work.